# phase tracking loop for dbpsk

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

I have a communication with a DBPSK modulation. The communication is disrupted by a Doppler shift (due to movement) and Doppler spread (due to channel). At the reception, after Doppler shift compensation with a preamble and DBPSK demodulation, I have a problem with the phase of the symbols. To correct the phase error, I use a phase tracking loop. Here is the link on what I'm doing [phase tracking loop](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjr2eWztvreAhVvyoUKHekBD4AQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.ensc.sfu.ca%2Fpeople%2Ffaculty%2Fcavers%2FENSC805%2Fnotedemo%2Fphase%2520tracking.htm&usg=AOvVaw2oBBlJIp-audkPHa_OR2GH).

Here are my questions:

1) How to choose the constant loop $K_c$?

2) We suppose the Doppler shift is perfectly compensated. In my Matlab code, if for example I take $K_c=0.01$, sometimes I find exactly the symbol sent and sometimes I have symbol errors. What is the reason for these errors?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to get this straight: you're doing DBPSK, but you're still seeing a constant phase error that has a non-zero mean?

That means you've got a frequency error.

Your assumption

> We suppose the Doppler shift is perfectly compensated

hence must be wrong.

So, correct frequency instead of the phase. You're already using **D**BPSK because you don't want to correct the absolute phase (I hope this was known to you. If you didn't know why you did differential modulation: please go and read up on differential phase shift keying, and why you don't use a phase-correcting loop with D(B)PSK).